# Redirection to WhatsApp application from custom URL

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, whatsapp

I have to prepare an analysis about redirecting from a web site to the WhatsApp appication in the purpose to send a message. I read the documentation at https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/28000012 and I noticed the use of **whatsapp://send?text** inside the href attribute of a link.

I want to know the behavior of this feature when WhatsApp is not installed in the user device and I found nothing about in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats what you called deep linking. Using hyperlinks to redirect to your app when installed and to play store (if deployed to play store) when not installed. One example that uses deep linking is facebook, but facebook uses http uri which you can choose to open to the app or to the browser as the http uri scheme is known to be a browser's uri. If you are using custom uri, then the deep link must be triggered by a browser. Refer Here for example using deeplink in chrome browser https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents